# Пунктуация в предложении: "Я жалкий проситель милости, в ноги кидаюсь всем"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Я жалкий проситель милости, в ноги кидаюсь всем.

Правильна ли пунктуация в предложении? Нужна ли тут запятая? Какое правило её объясняет, если да.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможные варианты.

1. С обособленным приложением:

Я, жалкий проситель милости, в ноги кидаюсь всем.

2. С БСП:

Я жалкий проситель милости, в ноги кидаюсь всем.
Я жалкий проситель милости: в ноги кидаюсь всем.
Я жалкий проситель милости — в ноги кидаюсь всем.

Answer (score 2):

Возможны два варианта.

(1) **Я, жалкий проситель милости, в ноги кидаюсь всем.** Обособленное приложение.

(2) **Я жалкий проситель милости, (я) в ноги кидаюсь всем.**

Сложное предложение, в первом предложении: ***я*** ― подлежащее, ***проситель*** ― сказуемое, тире после местоимения нет.